# How to pronounce the “的” in “他妈的”?

Tags: pronunciation, swearing

How usually native chinese speaker pronounce the “的” orally in “他妈的”? Is it "Ta Ma De" or "Ta Ma Di"?

Comment: Can you please provide some more context?

Comment: 你他妈的给我滚出去 (note: it's just an example)

Comment: In your example, 他妈的 is used as a swear word, meaning F***. Therefore, `Ta Ma De` is the correct pronunciation. In fact, even if it is used in other non-swearing contexts (meaning _His mom's_), it is normally pronounced as `Ta Ma De` as well.

Comment: I think the Di use is just a slang use or sometimes people try to put some humour into the swearing. Should be De

Answer (score 11):

The only correct answer is "TA MA DE".

This is the equivalent version of "F**K" in Chinese. I never hear people pronounce as "Di".

Thinking it in other way, it will be too soft and feminine if it's pronounced as "Di". It supposed to be strong and speak with hatred.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: @Sherlock Actually one other correct answer would be, if you are at this level, then do not say 他妈的 at all.

Answer (score 5):

"他媽的" is a brief form of "他媽的屄(bi)", where 屄(bi) is a noun, meaning = woman's sex organ (may be offensive for somebody)

So the pronunciation of 的 here should be /de/ in neutral tone.

Answer (score 4):

Should be De, although 的 can also be pronounced as Di, but it has a different usage, such as 的確, 目的.

Answer (score 4):

The 的 has two kinds of pronunciation, De and Di. Different pronunciation is used for different cases.

In 他妈的, the 的 is pronounced like: De, which makes the whole thing: Ta Ma De.

I never hear people say Ta Ma Di.

In case you didn't know, 他妈的 or 他麻痹(Ta Ma Bi) means Mother F**ker in English.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

De and Di and both accurate.  Di is more colloquial.

Comment: What do you mean? I would say this expression is very colloquial in itself, so saying that one pronunciation is more colloquial makes little sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

De or Di would both work depending on the regions of China.

Comment: Please elaborate more...

Answer (score 2):

In my region, Shandong Province, it's pronounced as tE ma de